# Limit Number of Items Displayed in Legend - GGplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, legend

I have a large taxonomic dataset that I need to plot as a stacked bar chart. Sample Data:

```
ID  X   A   B   C   D   E   F   G
1   5   9   6   7   4   8   10  6
2   6   3   9   10  3   10  4   8
3   6   6   5   8   8   8   8   1
4   9   3   2   8   4   1   5   8
5   6   6   2   8   3   7   4   10
6   0   7   8   9   1   4   9   10
7   3   2   6   8   8   1   8   7
8   4   7   10  2   9   7   9   8
9   5   7   9   10  8   2   2   1
10  0   4   6   8   9   10  7   1
11  8   9   2   2   6   5   1   7
12  8   6   0   9   7   9   8   1
13  2   8   4   4   4   2   6   7
14  4   6   6   4   9   9   3   5
15  8   1   0   6   5   8   1   1
16  6   6   9   3   9   2   1   1
17  2   4   0   2   4   8   10  9
18  5   9   8   9   4   9   3   9
19  0   2   1   6   6   9   6   2
20  3   3   7   10  4   5   6   8
21  2   6   6   9   8   10  9   4
22  7   7   1   6   8   3   7   1
23  1   9   4   5   8   9   7   7
24  0   8   5   9   1   8   9   1
25  2   1   0   1   1   2   10  7
26  10  4   1   8   2   5   9   0
27  2   7   10  10  2   3   8   6
28  6   4   2   6   7   3   1   0
29  8   1   3   4   1   10  3   6
30  1   6   5   4   7   9   7   10
31  4   4   3   2   2   9   0   4
32  9   6   6   1   6   1   5   2
```

The plotting part is no problem, using gggplot as below:-

```
l5 <- read.xlsx(paste(taxawmeta,taxawmeta_files[2], sep = ""), sheetIndex = 1)

l5_long <- l5 %>% gather(taxa,value,-c(X.FinalSampleID,TimePoint_Luna))

ggplot(l5_long, aes(fill=taxa, y = value, x = X.FinalSampleID, )) +
  geom_bar(position='stack', stat='identity') +
  theme_minimal() + 
  labs(x='Sample', y='Relative Abundance', title='Family Level Relative Abundance') +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        legend.position="none")
```

Where I'm running into an issue is the actual dataset has almost 200 variables. Meaning the legend is completely out of control. I know I can just hide the legend with:-

```
theme(.position="none")
```

... but what I'd like to do is keep say the top 10 entries as those are the ones of most interest. Is there any simple method to limit the number of items that are displayed in the legend? Anything I've found so far seems very convoluted and not directly applicable to this problem.

Comment: You could set categories to be displayed via the `breaks` argument, e.g. `scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c("A", "B"))` will only show A and B

Comment: You might also use `forcats::fct_lump` to pick an arbitrary number of categories to shade and label, with the others going into "other." It is hard to quickly distinguish more than about 10-12 colors, so 200 will be impossible.